Is it normal or concerning that a significant number of users are accessing my website through Tor?
There would be absolutely no reason to access my website through Tor. It is just a plain old website that has no (controversially or politically) interesting information and is primarily used for work.
But in a traffic analysis I have conducted a few days ago (by running records past TorDNSEL2 and checking if the IPs match public exit nodes) shows that about 3-4% of people accessing (as in visiting but not necessarily logging in) to my site are using Tor. Around a quarter to half of those are actually logging in, in case that's relevant.
I was able to find roughly estimated statistics that around 1-2.5% percent of all internet use is through Tor, but I'd have suspected that this would be to access sites that are banned for political or illegal reasons. Or to access site that may pose a risk to the user.
So I want to know, firstly, is this amount high, low, or normal? And also, even is this high, is it necessarily a bad thing- and should I take action to possibly restrict these figures?
I am probably being overly conservative but it just seems a bit strange that a much higher percent of people are accessing my website than accessing other  public sites on average. I am also just interested as to what reasoning people have towards doing this as I can guarantee that no government would even bother banning or flagging it as a 'threat.'

It is certainly reasonable to be acutely aware of this and ask the kinds of questions you are asking - although I am not sure how much help we can be.
I manage a reasonable number of websites for a range of clients (but most of my clients are local, and most legitimate traffic is local. so not an apples-for-apples comparison) but I've not seen any significant traffic on my network comming through Tor.
The clients logging in may both be useful and help you work out if this is a security risk.
I would look at the log files and see if there is anything more suspicious then the requests comming from TOR.   I'd also reach out to some of these logged in users (if you know them and they are active on your system) - and ask them to confirm if they are using Tor - which could help you ascertain if it is legimate users or if its compromised accounts/back-doored accounts/accounts used for hacking.
